# How to save output of for loop in separate csv files?

Tags: r, csv, for-loop

As an image and code that I attached below, I have a set of transaction data and each row has its industry name.

reproducible example data:

```
structure(list(Date = c(1201, 1201, 1201, 1201, 1201, 1201, 1201, 
1201, 1201, 1201), Sex = c("Male", "Male", "Female", "Male", 
"Male", "Female", "Male", "Female", "Male", "Male"), Age = c(10, 
15, 20, 15, 40, 50, 20, 30, 50, 20), City = c("Pheonix", "Atlanta", 
"Las Vegas", "Las Vegas", "Denver", "Pheonix", "Atlanta", "Las Vegas", 
"Las Vegas", "Minneapolis"), State = c("Arizona", "Georgia", 
"Nevada", "Nevada", "Colorado", "Arizona", "Georgia", "Nevada", 
"Nevada", "Minesota"), Industry = c("food", "furniture", "clothes", 
"transportation", "leisure", "food", "furniture", "food", "transportation", 
"furniture"), `no.of users` = c(48, 50, 83, 111, 186, 196.7, 
230.4, 264.1, 297.8, 331.5), `no. of approval cases` = c(48, 
21, 25, 48, 70, 63.7, 70.8, 77.9, 85, 92.1), `Total spending` = c(1541000, 
512000, 1757000, 1117000, 1740500, 1634700, 1735100, 1835500, 
1935900, 2036300)), .Names = c("Date", "Sex", "Age", "City", 
"State", "Industry", "no.of users", "no. of approval cases", 
"Total spending"), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

What I would like to do is to subset only rows whose industry names match a condition and export it as separate csv files with the name of the file corresponding to its industry name.
For example, let's say I have a list of

```
 current_industry<-c("food","furniture")
```

First, I would like to subset rows whose industry names match `"food"` and then save it to `csv files` name 'food', then subsetting the following rows whose industry name matches to `"furniture"` and save it as separate `csv files` name 'furniture'.

I wrote for-loop to do this, but this doesn't work as the following subsetting data replace the one beforehand.

```
for(i in current_industry){
  write.csv(subset(masterset, industry == i), "i.csv")}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wEBGz.png)

Comment: Please share the `masterset` as a reproducible example. Use `dput` to share it so that we can test how to solve your problem.

Comment: You need something like `paste0(i, ".csv")` as second parameter to write.csv

Comment: Sorry, forgot to share example. I edited to share reproducible example. thanks.

Comment: What you mean by second parameter? can you explain it in more deatil? thanks..!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will work. After running this code, you will find `food.csv` and `furniture.csv` in your working directory.

```
current_industry <- c("food", "furniture")

for (i in current_industry){
  dt2 <- subset(dt, Industry %in% i)
  write.csv(dt2, paste0(i, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

#### Update

You may also consider the following. This code will save all industry as separated CSV file in your working directory.

```
dt_list <- split(dt, f = dt$Industry)

lapply(dt_list, function(dt){
  write.csv(dt, paste0(unique(dt$Industry), ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
})
```

And the following will save only `food` and `furniture`. The key is to use `current_industry` to subset `dt_list`.

```
dt_list <- split(dt, f = dt$Industry)

dt_list2 <- dt_list[current_industry]

lapply(dt_list2, function(dt){
  write.csv(dt, paste0(unique(dt$Industry), ".csv"), row.names = FALSE)
})
```